# Removing unwanted NULL results when using Right join

Tags: mysql

Currently I've got two different tables, one named "Student" and another named "Class". I'd like to pick out one SPECIFIC Classcode from the Student table, while also picking out all the available Classcodes in the Class table. So far the best result I got was by using RIGHT JOIN which kinda gave me what I wanted. However instead of just displaying the specific Classcode from Student which I asked for, it displays the rest of them as "NULL". Code I used is posted below:

```
SELECT Student.Classcode, Class.Classcode               
FROM Student                                    
RIGHT JOIN Class
        ON Student.Classcode=Class.Classcode
       AND Student.Username='test'
ORDER BY Student.Classcode;
```

This provides me with the following result:

[image: table]

As you can see, it gives me the Classcode linked to the username on the left side (INF2), while showing all available classcodes on the right side. However for those that are NOT linked with the specified username, it shows up as NULL. Is there any way for it to show my desired Classcode without including the results that DONT match with the set username?

Comment: Could you add the expected result? It sounds to me you want to have to independent lists that are displayed side by side, one with 1 row, the other with 4 rows. That's not how it works, the two columns are related to each other, and all fields will be there (even if it is `null`, indicating there is no value). You can replace `null` by something else if you want, but that field will still be part of the result. To get 2 different resultsets, use two different queries and display them in your app side by side.

Comment: Why just not use INNER JOIN if You do not want not matched rows?

Answer (score 2):

This is a job for INNER JOIN, not RIGHT JOIN.

Inner joins give results only when there is a match in both tables.  Right and left joins give results for all rows in either the right-side table or the left-side table with NULL values in columns from the joined table when there is no match.

Here's a an example to help visualize it:

```
mysql> select * from a;
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|    1 |
|    2 |
|    3 |
|    4 |
|    5 |
+------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from b;
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|    3 |
|    4 |
+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

With the INNER JOIN, only rows with matching values of the "id" column in both tables are returned:

```
mysql> select a.id, b.id from b inner join a on (a.id = b.id);
+------+------+
| id   | id   |
+------+------+
|    3 |    3 |
|    4 |    4 |
+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

With the right join, all the rows from table "a" are returned, with NULL for the values from table "b" when there is no matching row in "b":

```
mysql> select a.id, b.id from b right join a on (a.id = b.id);
+------+------+
| id   | id   |
+------+------+
|    3 |    3 |
|    4 |    4 |
|    1 | NULL |
|    2 | NULL |
|    5 | NULL |
+------+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you really, really insist on using RIGHT JOIN for this, suppress the rows with NULL values by using WHERE.  Example:

```
mysql> select a.id, b.id from b right join a on (a.id = b.id) WHERE b.id is not null;
+------+------+
| id   | id   |
+------+------+
|    3 |    3 |
|    4 |    4 |
+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've set up a sample using this data: ([rextester](http://rextester.com/GLVB27046))

```
create table if not exists _Class(ClassCode text);
insert into _Class values 
('INF1'),
('INF2'),
('INF3'),
('IT1'),
('IT2');

create table if not exists _Students(StudentID text, ClassCode text);
insert into _Students values 
('John', 'INF1'),
('John', 'IT1'),
('Peter', 'INF3'),
('Peter', 'IT2');
```

According to your question:

> while also picking out all the available Classcodes in the Class table

This means that you first should try to fetch all Classcodes in Class table:

```
select ClassCode
from   Class;
```

The other part of your question:

> I'd like to pick out one SPECIFIC Classcode from the Student table

This is not clear to me, because you're trying to get Classcode from one specific Student in you subquery:

```
AND Student.Username='test'
```

Instead of one specific Classcode:

```
Student.Classcode = 'INF1'
```

Well, following you query you an use a LEFT JOIN, instead of a RIGHT JOIN, just to get all Classcode in this way:

```
select    _Class.ClassCode, coalesce(_Students.StudentID, '') as 'John Class'
from      _Class
left join _Students
on        _Class.ClassCode = _Students.ClassCode
and       _Students.StudentID = 'John';
```

This is the result:

```
+-----------+------------+
| ClassCode | John Class |
+-----------+------------+
|    INF1   |    John    |
|    IT1    |    John    |
|    INF2   |            |
|    INF3   |            |
|    IT2    |            |
+-----------+------------+
```